# Add a SQL Unique Constraint based on a field in a related parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am looking for the correct way to do this.
I am using Azure SQL.

Summary: Can I create a constraint like this:

```
 CONSTRAINT [UC_constraint_name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([field1_this_table] ASC, [field2_this_table] ASC, [Parent_Table].[Field_In_Parent_Table]) ASC)
```

**Detail**

I have two tables, a orders table and a items table.
A order will have multiple items.
Each order is assigned to a customer.
Each item has a unique bar-code assigned to it.
Bar-codes are currently unique on a customer level.
So Customer 1 can have the same bar-code as customer 2, but they cannot have internally duplicated bar-codes.

Simple and straight forward.

My current Constraint on the item_detail table is:

```
   CONSTRAINT [UC_unique_scan_code_customer_id] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([customer_id] ASC, [unique_scan_code] ASC),
```

Now, we have a customer that is duplicating bar-codes in different geographic regions.  So their West Coast operation may use the same bar-code as their Mid West operation.  They are still unique per geographic area.

I have added a new field (and a related table, but that should not matter here) at the order level called 'customer_geo_zone_number' and so that all of the items assigned to that order will be for that geo_zone.

My question, is should I duplicate the field 'customer_geo_zone_number' at the item level, or can I somehow have a unique constraint that uses the parent order table?

My initial solution was to just add the field, but that seems to break database normalization rules by storing the same field 'customer_geo_zone_number' in two tables that are related.

This is the constraint I have tried to add (to my item table), but this is not proper syntax (but it shows what I want to do):

```
CONSTRAINT [UC_unique_scan_code_customer_id2] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([customer_id] ASC, [unique_scan_code] ASC, [Order_Detail.customer_geo_zone_number]),
```

If it is helpful here is the current item table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[item_detail] (
[Id]               INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[job_id]           BIGINT          NULL,
[order_id]         BIGINT          NULL,
[customer_id]      INT             NOT NULL,
[unique_scan_code] VARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
[item_description] VARCHAR (100)   NULL,
[cust_code_1]      VARCHAR (100)   NULL,
[cust_code_2]      VARCHAR (100)   NULL,
[cust_code_3]      INT             NULL,
[cust_code_4]      DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
[container_type]   INT             NULL,
[record_created]   DATETIME        DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
[send_XML_flag]    BIT             DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
[dt_item_seq_no]   INT             NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_item_detail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [UC_unique_scan_code_customer_id] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([customer_id] ASC, [unique_scan_code] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_item_detail_To_Customer_Detail] FOREIGN KEY ([customer_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer_Detail] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_item_detail_To_Order_Detail] FOREIGN KEY ([order_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Order_Detail] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and here is the order table sql:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Detail] (
[Id]                           BIGINT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[customer_id]                  INT             NOT NULL,
[dt_unique_id]                 INT             NULL,
[dt_customer_no]               INT             NULL,
[customer_BOL]                 VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_unique_id]           VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
[customer_invoice_number]      VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_order_number]        VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_po_number]           VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_stop_id]             VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_route_id]            VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_terminal_id]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_del_route_seq_alpha] VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_del_route_seq_num]   INT             NULL,
[customer_misc_Vref_1]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_misc_Vref_2]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_misc_Vref_3]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_misc_Vref_4]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[customer_misc_Cref_1]         CHAR (1)        NULL,
[customer_misc_Cref_2]         CHAR (1)        NULL,
[customer_misc_Cref_3]         CHAR (1)        NULL,
[customer_misc_Cref_4]         CHAR (1)        NULL,
[customer_misc_Nref_1]         DECIMAL (18)    NULL,
[customer_misc_Nref_2]         DECIMAL (18)    NULL,
[customer_misc_Nref_3]         DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
[customer_misc_Nref_4]         DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
[Order_notes]                  VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[Pickup_Location_Id]           INT             NULL,
[Delivery_Location_Id]         INT             NULL,
[requested_pu_date]            DATETIME        NULL,
[requested_del_date]           DATETIME        NULL,
[expected_item_qty]            INT             NULL,
[record_created]               DATETIME        DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
[revenue_terminal_id]          INT             NULL,
[initial_route_id]             INT             NULL,
[delivery_branch_id]           INT             NULL,
[customer_geo_zone_number]     INT             NULL DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Order_Detail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [unique_cust_id_Orders_cust_unique_id] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([customer_id] ASC, [customer_unique_id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Detail_To_Customer_Detail] FOREIGN KEY ([customer_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer_Detail] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Detail_To_Terminal_Detail] FOREIGN KEY ([revenue_terminal_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Terminal_Detail] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Detail_To_Common_Address] FOREIGN KEY ([Delivery_Location_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Common_Address_Point] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Detail_To_Common_Address2] FOREIGN KEY ([Pickup_Location_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Common_Address_Point] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Detail_To_Route_Detail] FOREIGN KEY ([initial_route_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[route_detail] ([Id])
);
```

Comment: If the tables are for BI reporting (select ...) purpose only, FOREIGN KEY's are not necessary in that case.

Comment: I'm sorry, that does not seem to be related to my question -- unless I am missing something?

Comment: Instead of duplicating "customer_geo_zone_number" in item table, I would go with having it in parent "Order" table as you mentioned. Because "An entity type is in 1NF when it contains no repeating groups of data".

Comment: That is the purpose behind my question.  I want to do it that way, but I need to modify my unique constraint in my item table.  As it is it will not work.  Items are currently unique based on customer_id & unique_scan_code.  I need the additional field of customer_geo_zone_number added.  I do not know how to do that (or IF I can do that) without adding the field to the item table.

Comment: Not possible to alter the constraint. However you can drop and recreate. Hope tables are not live transnational !

Comment: Modify or not modify...drop or re-create.  Are you saying that there IS a way to have a constraint that uses fields from another table?  That is my question and how to write that constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been told that this is not possible (probably why no suggested solutions)
I am closing it out.